# Where to find polyfill names to add to babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill

The [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) link to [github.com/zloirock/core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) to obtain polyfills which can be used. We are currently using `es6.array.iterator`, `es6.promise`, `es7.promise.finally`, `es6.object.assign`, `es6.symbol`, `es6.map`. These mostly line up with what's on the github page but are not listed directly.

However I now wish to add [url and url-search-params](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams) but cannot work out what magic string to use in the babel config. Is there a list of all valid babel polyfills somewhere?

This is how our babel.config.js looks currently:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@vue/app',
            {
                polyfills: [
                    'es6.array.iterator',
                    'es6.promise',
                    'es7.promise.finally',
                    'es6.object.assign',
                    'es6.symbol',
                    'es6.map',
                ],
            },
        ],
    ],
    sourceType: 'unambiguous',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of `core-js` at first glance doesn't provide a list per se, but after some reading I found this [URL and SearchParams](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams). According to this docs I think you should include  `web.url`, `web.url.to-json`, `web.url-search-params` in your polyfills array to enable this features. However, I think there's a way to include `core-js` and then use something like `browserlist` to target only the browsers you need to support. Hope this helps you. Cheers, sigfried.

**EDIT:**
For the sake of completion I've included the options I was talking about as you can see this is a `React` project but I think that with a little adjustement you can make this work in a `Vue.js` project.

**EDIT #2:**
I think this is the list we were looking for :) [Core-JS Polyfills](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/v3.0.1/packages/core-js/modules)

**`babelrc`**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": ["last 2 versions", "not dead", "not < 2%"],
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

**`app.js`**

```
import React from 'react'
import '@babel/polyfill'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from './App'
import DefaultErrorBoundary from './DefaultErrorBoundary'
import './main.scss'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const axe = require('react-axe')
  axe(React, ReactDOM, 1000)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <DefaultErrorBoundary>
      <App />
    </DefaultErrorBoundary>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Your Core-JS Polyfills link is useful. It turns out we were stuck on an older version of core-js (2.6.1) due to a vue dependency, which is why we have older style names such as `es6.promise`. Going back to https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/v2.6.1 shows all the polyfills we can use (which sadly doesn't have url polyfills!)

Comment: Yes I saw the same as I digged deeper in the docs, the names have changed, sadly, anyhow I'm glad that this helped at least a little bit. Cheers